# Python Pandas: Most recent date there was trading on the NYSE exchange

Tags: python, pandas, date

I need to get the most recent date that there was trading on the NYSE exchange. For example, there is no trading on 11/25/2021, on the NYSE exchange. Therefore on November 26, the most recent trading day should be November 24. This is what I have so far but it's not working.

```
#import pandas market trading days calendar
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal

#create calendar of NYSE trading days
trading_days = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE').valid_days(start_date='2021-11-24', end_date='2021-11-26')

#print trading_days
print(trading_days)
```

> DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-24 00:00:00+00:00', '2021-11-26
> 00:00:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq='C')

```
#subtract 1 trading day from November 26, 2021
pd.to_datetime('11/26/2021') - pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(1, calendar = trading_days)
```

This should be the output

> Timestamp('2021-11-24 00:00:00')

Instead I'm getting:

> Timestamp('2021-11-25 00:00:00')

Comment: Please edit the question to include a sample input dataframe with expected output.

Comment: I edited the question with the expected output. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
date =  pd.to_datetime('11/26/2021') - pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(1, holidays = nyse.holidays().holidays)

2021-11-24 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you. That's perfect.